# show image in angular by safe url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want retur image with `blobl` request in angular in show it in html .

i using this code :

```
    <img [src]="ImageUrl"/>
```

in this is the ts code :

```
private src$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.Url);
    dataUrl$ = this.src$.subscribe(url => {
        return this.imageService.GetImage(url, this.id).subscribe(data => {
            this.ImageUrl=data.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
            return data.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity
        })
    });
```

and this is my service :

```
GetImage(url, id): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint+ url + id, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                if (res) {
                    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(res));
                }
                return null;
            })
        )
}
```

but when i need to show image it use this url in html :

```
<img src="unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/6868babb-5ab2-491f-b519-2f2a3d0ed351">
```

and not show me any image .

**whats the problem ? how  can i solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I ran into the same problem but I get to resolve it implementing in this way

In html

```
  <img [src]="transform(imageURI)" />
```

In ts

```
 transform(url) {
   return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
 }
```

Comment: hi askan . i think this is not good way beacuse when we use the function in html , every time we action on that page , that action called and not goof for browser performace

Comment: Have you tried replacing **bypassSecurityTrustUrl** in your code to **bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl**

Answer (score 0):

i try like this, and this solve for me
i hope this working for you

in my component

```
import { OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class myComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('myImage', { static: false }) private myImage: ElementRef


   ngOnInit() {
   }

   getMyImage(url: string): void {
    this.service.getImage(url)
        .subscribe(response =>
            this.myImage.nativeElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(response)
        )
   }
}
```

in my service

```
getImage(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api}/file/download/` + url, {responseType: 'blob'})
}
```

in my html

```
 <img #myImage>
```